# Why is this fwrite writing garbage?

Tags: c++, string, fwrite

I'm building a program that takes in serial data and saves it to file. Each line of data is timestamped. In this code, the timestamped line of data is s.

```
string s = get_timestamp();
cout << "input string named s is: " << s << "\n";  
numChars = sizeof(s);
cout << "size is: " << numChars << "\n"; 
fwrite( &s, sizeof(char) , numChars , DATA_LOG);
```

The print statements output

```
00000.27m,379named s is: 20130822.1141,00000.26m,379
size is: 28
```

You can see that for some reason the "input string named s" seems to be overwritten. This isn't really my main concern though (though I don't know why it's happening.)

My main problem is that my fwrite saves garbage to file. You can see that the numChars and string  are correct. I've tried in place of "&s", "static_cast(&s)" with the same garbage results. Any ideas?

Comment: Are we to assume `DATA_LOG` for this `stdout` ? And do you familiar with the term "buffered io" ?

Comment: What is the type of `s`?

Comment: I declared it as `FILE * DATA_LOG;`. It contains the filepath being written into. I believe the issue isn't with `DATA_LOG` because I've written into it correctly before. Buffered IO? Is it like storing IO to a buffer to write it all at once?

Comment: `std::string s;` sorry for leaving that out

Comment: Please specify the OS this is running on, as POSIX, Windows and MacOS have different newline conventions.

Comment: There's your problem. `sizeof`, applied to a `std::string` object, has nothing to do with the number of character stored in the string.

Comment: OS is Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: If `DATA_LOG` was opened in text mode, the system will take care of converting any `'\n'` characters in the data to the system's end-of-line sequence. (Yes, even for `fwrite`, which is requires to behave like a sequence of `fputc` calls.)

Comment: What you're writing to the file is the contents of the `std::string` object, *not* the sequence of characters that it manages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I suspect `s` contains some [carriage returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). This causes the cursor to move the beginning of the line, with further output overwriting what's already been printed. To see the actual character that get printed, redirect the output of your program to a file, and then use a hex editor/viewer (e.g. [`xxd`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html)) to examine the result.

Secondly, `sizeof(s)` is not the right way to determine the length of a `std::string`. Use `s.length()` instead. This is why `numChars` is incorrect.

Lastly, to write the string to the file, use:

```
fwrite( s.data(), sizeof(char) , s.length() , DATA_LOG);
```

Comment: "newline" is different in different operating systems as well.  Try using "\r\n" at end of each line, just in case.

Comment: @Roboprog: Just in case? Why would you want to write `"\r\n"` to a file on a system that uses just `"\n"` as a line terminator? If the file is opened in text mode, `fwrite` will convert any newlines in the data to the system's end-of-line representation anyway.

Comment: @KeithThompson:  so cursor goes to the left margin, and drops a line, regardless of which OS you view the file on via"cat" or "type".  Text mode should take care of it, but paranoia can be useful.

Comment: @Roboprog: So you generate a text file on a Unix system that has an extraneous `'\r'` characters at the end of each line. And if you run it on Windows, the normal text-mode handling will cause each line to end in `"\r\r\n"`. `cat` or `type` may not have a problem with it, but other tools will. `grep 'foo$' file.txt` will never match, because `foo` will never be at the end of a line (it will always be followed by `\r`).

Answer (score 1):

Writing a `std::string s` to a file would look something like this:

```
fwrite(s.c_str(), 1, s.size(), DATA_LOG);
```

There may be other issues with your data, looking at the console printout, but I'm not sure without seeing the actual data in a debugger or similar.

Comment: @MooingDuck: You mean to find the size of string's base-type? sizeof(s[0]) in that case?

Comment: `sizeof(s)`, i.e., `sizeof(std::string)`, is irrelevant. (Note that the size of a `std::string` object does not change as the length of the character sequence that it manages changes; it's all internal bookkeeping data.)

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(s)` should really be `strlen(s)` or `wcslen(s)`.

Or if you're using the `std::basic_string<>`, `.length()` will give you the length and `.c_str()` will give you the `char string pointer`, not `&s` which is the pointer to the actual object.

**So try**:

```
if(!s.empty()){
    fwrite(s.c_str(), sizeof(s.front()), s.length(), DATA_LOG);
}
```